What data type to pass to the interface for components in typescript
I created an interface for props for one of the components. This component is used multiple times elsewhere in the application. What I am passing to props is another component. Is this way of declaring data inside the interface OK?
interface MyProps {
  body: ComponentType;
}


const MyComponent = ({ body}: MyProps) => (
    <div>{body}</div>
);

export default MyComponent;

the props component is used as follows:
const Main = () => (
   <MyComponent body={<Form/>}/>
);

export default Main;


Change ComponentType to JSX.Element. Now I've given you enough metaphorical rope to hang yourself with. But you might want to google "how to pass a component as a prop in react" before proceeding.

Consider passing the elements as children instead, especially if you're only passing one root component  <MyComponent><Form /></MyComponent>. See https://www.dhiwise.com/post/react-pass-component-as-prop-guide-to-component-composition

If you want any type of React component, you could use ReactNode instead. There's plenty of ways to type a React component, you might wanna check this brilliant answer that mentions the differences between each.

@moonstar This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.
